# Verificar checkbox apenas quando estiver marcado

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou fazendo uma verificação de um check box para saber se tem um type="radio" selecionado. 
O problema que o check está executando o calculo mesmo quando eu desmarco o check box. 
Fiz o seguinte teste para ver o que estava acontecendo.

```
console.log($("input[type='checkbox'][id='SavePaper']").is(':checked') );
```

O resultado do teste foi:

true 
false

false 
true

true 
false

Segue a imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porque isso acontece e como resolver?

**Atualização:** código do checkbox

```html
<div class="md-checkbox" onclick="getValue()">
     <input type="checkbox" id="SavePaper" name="SavePaper" class="md-radiobtn">
      <label for="SavePaper">
          <span class="inc"></span>
          <span class="check"></span>
          <span class="box"></span>
      </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Não tem a ver diretamente com a tua questão, mas tendo em conta que os id's devem ser unicos no DOM (página) porque não fazes simplesmente: `$('#SavePaper').is(':checked');`. Pensando um pouco melhor o teu problema pode vir daí. Os dois botões apesar de terem o mesmo `type`, não podem ter id's iguais. corrige isso e vê se o problema se mantém

Comment: deu exatamente mesma coisa

Comment: vou colocar codigo do checkbox...

Comment: Atualizei o comentário acima. Eu não disse que resolveria o problema, só disse que ficaria melhor

Comment: Eles não estão com ids iguais

Comment: O checkbox está com um e o radio está com outro

Comment: Deves colocar o código que tens (de preferência funcional, em snipet) para que seja mais facil ajudar-te

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63797/discussion-between-gabrielfalieri-and-miguel).

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#SavePaper").click(function(e) {
     if($(this).is(':checked')){
         if ( $("input[type='radio'][name='Licenciamentodeusuários']").is(':checked') ){
             valor = $('input:radio[name=Licenciamentodeusuários]:checked').val();

             if(valor == "Até") {

                 if ($("#Ate-Comercial").val() != undefined) {
                     qtdUsuarios = $("#Até-Comercial").val();
                     vlrFinal = qtdUsuarios * 0.99;
                     console.log(vlrFinal);
                 }
                 if ($("#Até-Educacional").val() != undefined) {
                     qtdUsuarios = $("#Até-Educacional").val();
                     vlrFinal = qtdUsuarios * 0.99;
                     console.log(vlrFinal);
                 }
                 if ($("#Até-Profissional").val() != undefined) {
                     qtdUsuarios = $("#Até-Profissional").val();
                     vlrFinal = qtdUsuarios * 0.99;
                     console.log(vlrFinal);
                 }
             }else{

                 valor = valor.replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ');
                 valor = valor.split(" ");

                 vlrFinal = valor[2] * 0.99;
                 console.log(vlrFinal);

             }
         }

     }

 });
```

Resolvido.

Comment: Poderia acrescentar uma explicação do que foi feito para corrigir o erro